# PHP: fgets() return value not evaluated correctly?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that's supposed to do something depending on whether the first line of a file called info.txt is '0' or something else. My PHP file:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('info.txt','r');
$line = fgets($handle);
fclose($handle);

// print detailed contents of $line
foreach(str_split($line) as $chr) {
  printf("[%02x] %s <br />",ord($chr),$chr);
}

if ($line == '0\n') {
  echo "equal";
} else {
  echo "not equal";
}
?>
```

I got the foreach loop on another answer on stackoverflow and it splits `$line` by character and prints the character's code and what it evaluates to. When I run this file the output is:

```
[30] 0  
[0a]  
not equal
```

It looks like the first line of info.txt is just `0\n` since as I understand it, `0x0a` should be the same as `\n`. I'm running this file on Mac OS X but I thought that shouldn't change the fact that ASCII `0x0a` is the `\n` character. Any ideas why `$line` isn't evaluating as equal to `'0\n'`? I'm new to PHP so it's very possible that the issue is some obvious syntax thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use double quotes instead of simple quotes so that "\n" is interpreted as new line character. With single quotes, the characters are interpreted as '\' + 'n' characters.

```
if ($line == "0\n") {
        echo "equal\n";
    } else {
        echo "not equal\n";
    }
```